# SonarQube Web API Service: Only get issues from a rule repository

Tags: web-services, sonarqube

I am developing a script to use for getting issues from SonarQube. I know the syntax for getting a specific rule is adding the following to the url:

> rules=repository:rule

However, what if I want to get all the issues from a repository such as findbugs? What do I put in the rule section?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.7.5 LTS I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [SonarQube Web Service API documentation for rules](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743284#WebService/api/rules-GetaListofRules), the correct way to list all rules for a given rule repository is to use the `plugin`parameter, e.g: http://nemo.sonarsource.org/api/rules?language=java&plugin=pmd,findbugs